# Replace a substring using bash script

Tags: bash, parsing, unix

I am trying to replace a substring of a string in a file called db_config using bash.

code in db_config file is

```
dbname=test_1
```

I want to replace "test_1" to "production".

The substring can be *test_1* or *test1* or *testing* or any random string but the format will be **dbname=(whatever the name)**

This needs to be changed to **dbname=production**

I tried both these syntax. Neither worked.

```
sed -i -e 's/dbname=*/dbname="ihs"/g' db_config

sed -i -e 's/dbname=$/dbname="ihs"/g' db_config
```

I know how to parse this in python but i cant seem to find a solution in bash.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a capture group and `.*` to match everything after keyname:

```
sed -i 's/^[[:blank:]]*\(dbname=\).*/\1production/' db_config
```

- `^[[:blank:]]*` match optional white-spaces before `dbname=`
- There is no need of `g` flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, anubhava. This worked. Thanks for explaining the solution too.